# Consulta ahorcado javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera consultar si alguien descubre cual es el problema en el codigo que dejo del juego ahorcado.

tengo un boton con el id `test-letter`, el cual la idea seria recorrer un array donde guarde la palabra y la compara con el `val()` de un input.

El problema es que algo falla porque no esta comparandolo.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

     //name = prompt('Cual es tu nombre');

     //var h2Name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;

     var words = ['pala','martillo','pico','pelota','guante', 'la']; 
     var answerWord = [];
     var hiddenWord = [];

     // function to pick a random word from words array
     function pickWord() {
      hiddenWord.pop();
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* words.length); 
      var randomWord = words[randomNumber];

      var divWord = $('.word-container');
      var splitRandomWord = randomWord.split('');
      hiddenWord.push(splitRandomWord);

      divWord.html('');
      for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
       var letter = answerWord[i] = '_';
       divWord.append('<p class="letters">'+ letter + '</p>');
       
      };
     };

     function resetArray(array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       array.pop();
      }
     }

     $('#start').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      resetArray(answerWord);
      pickWord();
     })
     $('#test-letter').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var letterToTest = $('.guess').find('input').val();

      if (letterToTest.length > 1) {
       alert('Ingrese solo una letra')
      } else if (letterToTest === '') {
       alert('Debe ingresar una letra')
      } else {

       for (var i = 0; i < hiddenWord.length; i++) {
        console.log(hiddenWord[i]);
        console.log(letterToTest);
        if (letterToTest === hiddenWord[i]) {
         console.log('encontraste');
        }
       }
      }
      
     });

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <div class="header">
      <div class="border-header">
      <h1>Ahorcado</h1>
      <h2 id="name"></h2>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="button-container">
      <div>
      <button id="start">Comenzar</button>
      <button id="reset">Resetear</button>
      </div> 
     </div>
     <div class="word-container">
     </div>
     <div class="guess">
      <input type="text" name="">
      <button id="test-letter">Probar</button>
     </div>


     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes con la variable `hiddenWord`. Esta variable es un array de objetos,y en la función `pickWord` lo que se guarda es un array de las letras que componen la palabra elegida al azar.Este array es el objeto que se almacena en `hiddenWord` con lo la longitud de `hiddenWord` es 1, lo que hace que el bucle solo se repita una vez.

Posteriormente tratas de comparar la letra introducida con la primera posición de `hiddenWord`, que es el array de las letras de la palabra elegida y no coinciden logicamente. Lo que debes hacer es primero meter el array de letras en una variable y usar dicha variable en tu bucle de comparación.

Prueba a cambiar tu bucle por esto:

```
var letterarray=hiddenWord[0]; //Obtenemos el array de letras de la palabra a buscar
for (var i = 0; i < letterarray.length; i++) {
        console.log(letterarray[i]);
        console.log(letterToTest);
        if (letterToTest === letterarray[i]) {
            console.log('encontraste');
        }
}
```

---

Por otro lado, es un poco extraño el uso que haces de Push/Pop en ese código. En realidad en `hiddenword` lo lógico es que almacenaras el array de letras de la palabra elegida. Simplemente, quitando de la función `pickWord` el `hiddenWord.pop` y modificando la linea `hiddenWord.push(splitRandomWord);` por `hiddenWord = splitRandomWord;`, el resto del código funcionaría correctamente.

Comment: Tenias razon, elimine push/pop y modifique hiddenword. La realidad era que al clickear en comenzar, me cambiaba la palabra elegida pero no me actualizaba esa misma palabra para comprobar la letra, por eso la puse en una array con push, error mio. Arranque hace poco con esto.
Me esta funcionando bien, ahora vere como hago para que actualize los tag 'p' para que aparezca cada letra adivinanda.
Gracias!!